# Hiding long nodes name using JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I using `JTree` component.
As you can see, the name of the first node does not fit completely.

As it is possible to add at the very beginning an icon or an arrow icon so that when you click on it, the name of the node is shown with hyphens or full hiding. Please give some example of this.
Any help is needed.

Thank you.

Comment: Display the full text as a tooltip.  This is a fairly standard way to handle this.

Comment: My business customers want to hide and reveal the name. But I do not know how to do it.

Comment: I would say the complexity of the issue is greater then the available solutions.  That is, it would be very hard for the renderer to calculate if it's preferred width is going to extend beyond the viewable range of the `JScrollPane`, especially when you consider that the `JTree` indents the nodes, so each level would be different

Comment: @MadProgrammer, It may be easier to bind to the length of the name, well, for example, if it is more than 10 characters, add the ability to hide and display it, otherwise display as is

Comment: @All_Safe You're not taking into account the possibility of different font metrics which might be used across different OSes

Comment: @MadProgrammer, This is not very important, the program is used on the same OS

Comment: @All_Safe You'll be very, very surprised how differently the app is rendered across different computers of the same OS - magic numbers are a bad idea

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Yes, I understand this, but I can not think of another way to solve this problem. Tooltip is a good way, but it does not work in my case. They want that if the name is revealed, then it was shown always, and not just when you are navigating with the mouse.

Comment: @All_Safe I know you client might not like it, and I bet in their minds the solution they have is a good one, but, if you can, I'd suggest some alternatives which are simpler to implement and to use.  One might be investigating a multiple line render, can't say I've tried it, but it's an idea. I did write a solution which would overlay the tooltip over the position of the node, so it "appeared" to overflow the component.

Comment: @All_Safe You still have the same problem. There's no (reliable) way to know if the "leaf node" is going to generate a value which is to long to be displayed and if you could, you'd need to update the model to convert the "leaf node" to a "non-leaf" node, which would mess up the entire process and probably cause a considerable about of havoc (as the model is trying to update during a render pass, which would cause a render pass, but the first render pass hasn't complete yet and OMG...)

Comment: @All_Safe The "best, off the top of my head" solution I can think off, is start by creating ALL the leaf nodes with a "short name", which is the contains the "full name" as a child node

Comment: @MadProgrammer,Can at least have a way to display the name with hyphenation?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @MadProgrammer we cannot calculate exact width based on font metrics and indent of node at each level. But what we can restrict node name to max width of 10 ( are any index ) and add ... ate end to tell user it is not full text and add full text to tooltip. Here is the code for that.

```
    final int MAX_TEXT_WIDTH = 10;
    tree.setCellRenderer(new DefaultTreeCellRenderer(){
         public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
                  boolean sel,
                  boolean expanded,
                  boolean leaf, int row,
                  boolean hasFocus) {

             Object strValue = value;
             String tooltip = null;
             if( value instanceof Object ) {
                 String val = value.toString();
                 if( val.length() > MAX_WIDTH ) {
                     // truncate teh string and add ... at end so that user can
                     strValue = val.substring(0, MAX_WIDTH )+"...";                      
                 } else {
                     strValue = val;
                 }
                 tooltip = val;
             }

             Component comp =  super.getTreeCellRendererComponent( tree,strValue,sel,expanded,leaf,row,hasFocus);

             if ( comp instanceof JComponent ) {
                 JComponent jcomp =   ( JComponent ) comp;
                 jcomp.setToolTipText(tooltip);
             }
             return comp;
         }
    });
```